# Group_by multiple columns and summarise unique column

Tags: r, dplyr, r-markdown, tidyverse

I have a dataset below

| family | type | inc | name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AA | success | 30000 | Bill |
| AA | ERROR | 15000 | Bess |
| CC | Pending | 22000 | Art |
| CC | Pending | 18000 | Amy |
| AA | Serve not respnding d | 25000 | Paul |
| ZZ | Success | 50000 | Pat |
| ZZ | Processing | 50000 | Pat |

I want to group by multiple columns

here is my code bellow

```
df<-df1%>%
group_by(Family , type)%>%
  summarise(Transaction_count = n(), Face_value = sum(Inc))%>%
  mutate(Pct = Transaction_count/sum(Transaction_count))
```

what I want is that anywhere there is same observation Family, it should pick only one

like this result in the picture below.

[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `duplicated` to replace the repeating values with blank value.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(family , type)%>%
  summarise(Transaction_count = n(), Face_value = sum(inc))%>%
  mutate(Pct = Transaction_count/sum(Transaction_count), 
         family = replace(family, duplicated(family), '')) %>%
  ungroup

#   family type                     Transaction_count Face_value   Pct
#  <chr>  <chr>                                <int>      <int> <dbl>
#1 "AA"   ERROR                                    1      15000 0.333
#2 ""     Serve not respnding    d                 1      25000 0.333
#3 ""     success                                  1      30000 0.333
#4 "CC"   Pending                                  2      40000 1    
#5 "ZZ"   Processing                               1      50000 0.5  
#6 ""     Success                                  1      50000 0.5
```

If you want data for displaying purpose you may look into packages like `formattable`, `kable` etc.

**data**

It is easier to help if you provide data in a [reproducible format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)

```
df <- structure(list(family = c("AA", "AA", "CC", "CC", "AA", "ZZ", 
"ZZ"), type = c("success", "ERROR", "Pending", "Pending", "Serve not respnding    d", 
"Success", "Processing"), inc = c(30000L, 15000L, 22000L, 18000L, 
25000L, 50000L, 50000L), name = c("Bill", "Bess", "Art", "Amy", 
"Paul", "Pat", "Pat")), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = "data.frame")
```